# adjust vertical space after figure kaobook

Tags: floats, kaobook

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=10pt, %
    twoside=true, %
    open=any, %
    chapterentrydots=true, %
    numbers=noenddot %
]{kaobook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. }
\vspace{-20pt}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[3-4]

\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}
```

This works, but the `vertical space adjustment` not works after `figure`, but the caption was raised vertically which should not be, refer the shown image below:

[image]

How can I adjust the vertical space (either reduce/increase) after `figure` environment?

I'm very new to `kaobook`, so please excuse me if my question is silly...